# Tracking a person in a scene with a varying amount of illumination

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-vision

In computer vision, what would be a good approach to tracking a human in the black and white same scene at different times of the day (i.e. different levels of illumination)?  The scene will never be dark so I don't need to worry about searching using infra-red or anything for heat sensing.  I need to identify the people and then also track them so there are two parts.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked OpenCV? There's lots of examples included.

Answer (score 1):

SIFT feature matching works well for this purpose. It is implemented in OpenCV.